# Accessing State in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state

Is

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session
```

the same as

```
System.Web.UI.Page.Session
```

?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They do indeed refer to the same instance, but if you look at the methods in [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/), you can see that they behave a bit differently (in ways that are not likely to matter in most applications):

- The call to `Page.Session` uses a
  cached `HttpSessionState` *reference*.
- The `Page` method will throw if
  session state is not enabled, while
  `HttpSessionState.Session` just
  returns whatever is in the
  "AspSession" bucket of its `Items`
  collection.

Answer (score 5):

Yup; they refer to the same instance.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between the two.